# TypeScript interpretation of "this" keyword within $.ajax()

Tags: intellisense, typescript

I realize that the TypeScript compiler is attempting to stay true to plain old JavaScript, as TypeScript is indeed JavaScript.  However, there is a disconnect between what Intellisense interprets as the "this" keyword and what it actually resolves to during runtime.  For example, consider the following TypeScript ajax call:

```
 getAgencies() {
            var self = this;          
            $.ajax(liveString + "/Home/GetSupportedAgencies",
            {
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                error: Utilities.Logger.displayAjaxError,
                success: this.onGetAgenciesComplete
            });

        }
```

and its corresponding callback:

```
   onGetAgenciesComplete(agencies) {
                var self = this;
                    if (agencies == null)
                        Utilities.Logger.displayErrorOnLogConsole("There was an error retrieving supported agencies.  Refresh site and try again.");
                    else {
                        $.each(agencies, function (i, a) {
                            self._indexViewModel.agencies.push({ name: a.Name, fullName: a.FullName, shortName: a.ShortName, bbox: a.BBox, countryCode: a.CountryCode });
                        });

                        if (Modernizr.geolocation) {
                            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                                function (position) {
                                    self.initMapPage(position, self);
                                },
                                function (error) {
                                    Utilities.Logger.displayErrorOnLogConsole("Oops, we could not get your location at his time. Please try later.");
                                });
                        }
                        else {
                            Utilities.Logger.displayErrorOnLogConsole("Sorry, your browser does not return location information.");
                            self.getBusRoutes(self.agencyName);
                        }


                        // end of initialization
                    }
                }
```

Now, when I hover over line "var self = this" in onGetAgenciesComplete within the TypeScript source file, the Intellisense definition of variable "self" indicates it is of type HomePageViewModelBase, where HomePageViewModelBase is the class that contain the above methods.

The generated Javascript for aforementioned is as follows:

```
HomePageViewModelBase.prototype.getAgencies = function () {
            var self = this;
            $.ajax(liveString + "/Home/GetSupportedAgencies", {
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                error: Utilities.Logger.displayAjaxError,
                success: this.onGetAgenciesComplete
            });
        };
        HomePageViewModelBase.prototype.onGetAgenciesComplete = function (agencies) {
            var self = this;
            if(agencies == null) {
                Utilities.Logger.displayErrorOnLogConsole("There was an error retrieving supported agencies.  Refresh site and try again.");
            } else {
                $.each(agencies, function (i, a) {
                    self._indexViewModel.agencies.push({
                        name: a.Name,
                        fullName: a.FullName,
                        shortName: a.ShortName,
                        bbox: a.BBox,
                        countryCode: a.CountryCode
                    });
                });
                if(Modernizr.geolocation) {
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                        self.initMapPage(position, self);
                    }, function (error) {
                        Utilities.Logger.displayErrorOnLogConsole("Oops, we could not get your location at his time. Please try later.");
                    });
                } else {
                    Utilities.Logger.displayErrorOnLogConsole("Sorry, your browser does not return location information.");
                    self.getBusRoutes(self.agencyName);
                }
            }
        };
```

which when executed variable "self" in HomePageViewModelBase.prototype.onGetAgenciesComplete is resolved to what looks like an AjaxContext and not an instance of HomePageViewModelBase.  Is this expected behavior or should I report this as a bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you should probably report it to them as a bug, because the `this` within an `$.ajax()` is meant to refer to the `$.ajax()` object itself.

If you want to go around it so that it works, change your success function to:

```
success: self.onGetAgenciesComplete
```

Or if you *want* the `this` to stand for your class, simply use the **context** method of $.ajax

```
$.ajax({ 
    context: this,
    // now *this* will come from the previous scope,
    // which in your case, is your class "HomePageViewModelBase"

    // now that we know for certain what -this- refers to
    success: this.onGetAgenciesComplete
});
```

Comment: Good answer - setting the context works. Before you submit a bug though, consider this question: How can the compiler infer the context of `this` correctly when the function could be called in many different contexts. I believe it shows the correct context based on the assumption the function is called directly, rather than in the context of a callback from elsewhere.

Comment: I agree, and if anything it is good practice (if anything but also for readability) to make it obvious what the context of `this` should be here. I think @KNji's point was, shouldn't it know it is the `$.ajax` itself, since that is how it works within jQuery?

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS, that is a good explanation, thank you.  I never knew of the $.ajax context which is an even better solution.  Double thanks.  You are also correct in the point of my post which is intellisense should not have refered to "this" in $.ajax to an instance of HomePageViewModel base.

Answer (score 3):

As far as any (including Intellisense) static analysis is concerned, the context of `onGetAgenciesComplete` *is* `HomePageViewModelBase` and always will be; except that at runtime, the context will be set dynamically, via explicit internal jQuery.ajax context binding. The only way Intellisense could determine that the context will change dynamically is to actually execute that code path, but even that results in ambiguity: which context is the right context?

What if you "borrow" a method elsewhere, for a one-off call? Should Intellisense then use that call site to determine the context? Probably not...

```
HomePage.prototype.onGetAgencies.call({ some other context }, ...);
```

(Shortened for readability.)